# Format eleven digit number to string

Tags: java, string, formatter

I have number eleven digit number from my DB: 12345678910
I need to get this number in the following format:
123-456-789-10
How i can get it with standart Java?

Comment: `Integer.toString` to convert your number into a String, then a couple of `subString` calls interlaced with `+ "-" +`

Comment: How does it look from your DB?

Comment: @AmohPrince i get from DB: 12345678910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder`:

```
    long number = 12345678910L;
    String stringNumber = new StringBuilder(number + "")
            .insert(3, '-')
            .insert(7, '-')
            .insert(11, '-')
            .toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex after converting your number to string:

```
long number = 12345678910L;

String str = String.join("-", String.valueOf(number).split("(?<=\\G...)"));
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

11 digits might overflow an `int` so use a `long`.

```
long n = resultSet.getLong(...);

String formatN(long n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal " + n);
    }
    String d = String.format("%011d", n);
    if (d.length() > 11) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal " + n);
    }
    return d.substring(0, 3) + "-" + d.substring(3, 6)
        + "-" + d.substring(6, 9) + "-" + d.substring(9);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That number is way too long to be an Integer. It depends on the data type you pull from the database. Use a long instead.

```
    long yourInteger = 12345678910L;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String s = Long.toString(yourInteger);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i = i + 3) {
        if (s.length() - i > 3) {
            String subString = s.substring(i, i + 3);
            stringBuilder.append(subString);
            stringBuilder.append("-");
        }
    }

    stringBuilder.append(s.substring(s.length() - 2));

    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about like this.  Use [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).

- Convert the `long` to a String
- Replace every `3 digits` with those digits followed by a `-`
- `$0`- is the back reference to the string matched by the regex.

```
long value = 12345678910L;
String val = Long.toString(value).replaceAll("\\d\\d\\d","$0-");
System.out.println(val);
```

prints

```
123-456-789-10
```

This easily lends itself to a lambda

```
Function<Long, String> format = v->Long.toString(v).replaceAll("\\d\\d\\d","$0-");
String result = format.apply(value);
```

**Note:** If the number is a already a String or can be retrieved as one, you can forgo the `Long.toString()` conversion.